# Which set of functions admits the existence of the minimizer?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations, convex-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and consider the functional $J$ on $X$:

$$J[u] = \int_0^1 \left( (u'(x))^2 -a)^2 + b \ln (1+ u^2(x))\right) dx$$

Providing reasons specify if the $\inf J$ over $X$ is attained of not

1. $a>0, b \geq 0, X =\{ u \in C^1([0,1]); u(0)=0, u(1)=0 \}$
2. $a>0, b > 0, X =\{ u \in AC([0,1]); u(0)=0, u(1)=0 \}$
3. $a<0, b \geq 0, X =\{ u \in AC([0,1]); u(0)=0, u(1)=1 \}$

**My proof**

I am trying to apply the following theorem to find the answer.

**Special version of Tonelli’s theorem**

Assume that the function $f(x,u): [a,b] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x, \xi): [a,b] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, $f$ is bounded below, $g$ is convex in $\xi$ and satisfies

$$\exists r>1,\, \exists C>0\,\, \text{such that}\,\, g(x,\xi) \ge C| \xi|^r,\,\, \forall (x, \xi) \in [a,b] \times \mathbb{R}.$$

Then there exists a minimizer of the functional
$$J[u] = \displaystyle\int_a^b (f(x,u(x)) + g(x,u'(x))) dx$$ in the space $X= \{ u \in AC([a,b]); u(a)=\alpha, u(b)= \beta \}.$

Here I considered $f(x,u(x)) = b \ln (1+u^2(x))$ and $g(x,u'(x))= (u'(x)^2 -a)^2$. Am I in the right path? I am not sure on what should I do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to (3) is yes. Indeed, then all the conditions of what you call "special version of Tonelli’s theorem" (proved in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/413645/36721)) are satisfied.

The answer to (2) is no. Indeed, for natural $n$ and $x\in[0,1]$, let
$$u_n(x):=\sqrt a\,d(x,E_n),$$
where $E_n$ denotes the set $\{0,\frac1n,\frac2n,\dots,\frac nn\}$ and $d(x,E_n)$ denotes the shortest distance from $x$ to the set $E_n$. Then $u_n\in AC[0,1]$ and
$$J[u_n]=b\int_0^1\ln(1+u_n^2(x))\, dx\le b\ln(1+a/(4n^2))\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$. Since $J[\cdot]\ge0$, it follows that $\inf J[\cdot]=0$. However, this zero infimum is not attained at any $u$ -- if $J[u]=0$, then $u=0$ and hence $J[u]=a^2>0$.

The answer to (1) is no as well. This follows because the $u_n$'s as above can be appropriately approximated by $C_1$ functions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think you have meant (1) is no as well. However, I am finding some difficulties in satisfying the conditions in 3.

Comment: Can I apply this to case one? and how?


Regularity theorem
Let $\overline{u} \in \operatorname{Lib}[a,b]$ satisfy the integral Euler equation for the functional $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x,u(x),u'(x)) dx$, where for every $x \in [a,b]$ the function $\xi \to f(x,\overline{u}(x),\xi)$ is strictly convex. Then $\overline{u}$ lies in $C^1 [a,b]$.

Comment: @SelfLearner : (i) Thank you for spotting the typo. It is now fixed. (ii) What difficulties are you having concerning (3)? There, you just need to check all the conditions of the "special version of Tonelli’s theorem". Which of these conditions seem hard to check? (iii) I cannot parse your latter (longer) comment.